# How does radiation facilitate the formation of tetravalent iron?

Tags: electronic-configuration, metal, oxidation-state, electromagnetic-radiation

In reading the article abstract [What Oxidation State of Iron Determines the Amethyst Colour?](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004HyInt.156..417D), the author states that in regards to the gemstone amethyst, from clear quartz:

> The crystal was transformed into violet amethyst by gamma-irradiation. The change in colour was accompanied by changes in the Mössbauer spectrum that can be interpreted as the conversion of trivalent iron into the tetravalent state: $\ce{Fe^{3+}→Fe^{4+}}$

**How does gamma radiation facilitate the conversion of oxidation state of iron, from $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ to $\ce{Fe^{4+}}$?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ionization energy of $\ce{Fe^3+}$ to $\ce{Fe^4+}$ is 54.8 eV.
The energy of typical gamma radiation is much higher (in the order of roughly some keV to a few MeV). Depending on the energy, the interaction of average gamma radiation with the affected electron is mainly due to Compton scattering.