# How is the triferric tetroxide of iron possible?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

If oxygen has a valency of $-2$, $4$ of it would result in $-8$. But iron doesn't have a (variable) valency of anything that goes to $-8$. Then how is $\ce{Fe3O4}$ possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iron, like many of the Transition Metals *does* have a variable valency, it can valencies of 2+ ([ferrous iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrous)), 3+ ([ferric iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferric)) and in some cases, 4+ ([tetravalent iron](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28751/15489)).

In regards to $\ce{Fe3O4}$, according to the Wikipedia page [Iron(II,III) oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(II,III)_oxide),

> contains both $\ce{Fe^2+}$ and $\ce{Fe^3+}$ ions

A 2-dimensional diagram of $\ce{Fe3O4}$ is below, from the relevant [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.17215625.html) page:

[image]

A 3-dimensional model is below (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(II,III)_oxide)):

[image]

*red indicate oxygen*